# remove marker when is deleted since firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, marker

I'm new to Android, I followed this tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/realtime-asset-tracking/index.html#0

for real-time tracking, all right, my question is how do I delete a marker from the map when it is deleted in firebase, the code is as follows:

```
private void subscribeToUpdates() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("locations").child("unidad_1");
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarker(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarker(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            removeMarker(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}

private void removeMarker(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

    if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
        mMarkers.remove(key);
    }
}


private void setMarker(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // When a location update is received, put or update
    // its value in mMarkers, which contains all the markers
    // for locations received, so that we can build the
    // boundaries required to show them all on the map at once
    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
        mMarkers.put(key, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(location)));
    } else {
        mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);
    }


    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker marker : mMarkers.values()) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 0));
}
```

What is the correct way to make this work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link under it) to include the code for `setMarker` too. Without that it's hard to guess why `removeMarker` doesn't work.

Comment: I've already update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `removeMarker()` method change your code to look like this:

```
if (mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
    Marker marker = mMarkers.remove(key);
    if(marker != null){
        marker.remove();
    }
}
```

I am assuming that `mMarkers` is a `HashMap`. In which case removing the entry with `remove(key)` will remove the entry from your `HashMap` and return the `Marker` (or null if it doesn't exist). Then just use the `remove` method of the marker to remove it from the map.

Another problem with your code is you check if the `HashMap` does NOT contain the **key**. So that code would probably not execute.

EDIT

You may have confused `mMarker` the `HashMap` with the `Marker` of the `Map`.  "mMarker" is not a good name for coding -- as it is not obvious. You should change it to something more obvious like "mMarkerMap".

Comment: Thank you
It has worked! 
I will take your  to improve the code